# Form Submits even through jQuery returns false

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, return

The issue I am having is that the form still submits even though the code is made to return false if and or all of the fields are empty.

My HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="contactForm" id="contactForm">
    <input type="text" name="contactName" id="contactName" class="contactTextfield" />
    <input type="text" name="contactPhone" id="contactPhone" class="contactTextfield" />
    <input type="text" name="contactEmail" id="contactEmail" class="contactTextfield" />
    <textarea name="contactMessage" id="contactMessage" class="contactTextarea" rows="5"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="contactSubmit" id="contactSubmit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

My jQuery:

```
$("#contactForm").submit( function() {
    var contactName = $("#contactName").val();
    var contactEmail = $("#contactEmail").val();
    var contactMessage = $("#contactMessage").val();
    var emailFormat = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

    if ( contactEmail != '' && emailFormat.test(contactEmail) ) {
        var contactEmailCheck = true;   
    }

    if ( contactName != '' ) {
        var contactNameCheck = true;
    }

    if ( contactMessage != '' ) {
        var contactMessageCheck = true;
    }

    if ( contactEmailCheck == true && contactNameCheck == true && contactMessageCheck == true ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

FIXED:

Turned out it was not working because the jquery code was in the header of the index page while the form itself was only loaded onto the page via ajax from a separate html file. I had to place the jquery code inside the same file as the form.

Comment: see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NBGmY/). I see no problem there

Comment: what data is entered into fields when `return false` does not work?

Answer (score 1):

This is a scoping issue.. Assign you variables outside the if statemenets..

Try this

```
$("#contactForm").submit(function() {
    var contactName = $("#contactName").val();
    var contactEmail = $("#contactEmail").val();
    var contactMessage = $("#contactMessage").val();
    var emailFormat = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

    var contactEmailCheck = false;
    var contactNameCheck = false;
    var contactMessageCheck = false;
    if (contactEmail != '' && emailFormat.test(contactEmail)) {
        contactEmailCheck = true;
    }

    if (contactName != '') {
        contactNameCheck = true;
    }

    if (contactMessage != '') {
        contactMessageCheck = true;
    }

    if (contactEmailCheck && contactNameCheck && contactMessageCheck) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});​
```

Comment: There is no difference.  Once it is not set to true `contactName == ''`, for instance, contactNameCheck will be undefined. and no errors. Also it will be correctly handled by the last if statement (undefind != true)

Comment: JS has no `if statement scope`

Comment: variables in javascript have function scope, not block scope. Moving variable declarations to the top of the function is good practice and makes the code more readable, but is not necessary.  You can actually use a variable before you declare it with `var` due to variable hoisting.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend this : 
Change your input type of Send button from 'Submit' to 'Button' first.

```
<input type="button" name="contactSubmit" id="contactSubmit" value="Send"/>
```

Bind a click event to this button in jquery document ready function or anywhere else you think is right. And on click of that Send button call a function where you do all validations and submit your form from there if everything is fine otherwise show errors or alerts.

```
#('#contactForm').click(function(){
    validateForm();
});
```

Also in your function written ro validate form has some scoping issues.

```
function validateForm() {
    var contactName = $("#contactName").val();
    var contactEmail = $("#contactEmail").val();
    var contactMessage = $("#contactMessage").val();
    var emailFormat = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    var contactEmailCheck = false;
    var contactNameCheck = false;
    var contactMessageCheck = false;

    if ( contactEmail != '' && emailFormat.test(contactEmail) ) {
        contactEmailCheck = true;
    }

    if ( contactName != '' ) {
        contactNameCheck = true;
    }

    if ( contactMessage != '' ) {
        contactMessageCheck = true;
    }

    if ( contactEmailCheck == true && contactNameCheck == true && contactMessageCheck ==     true ) {
        //submit form from here since everything is fine
        $('#contactForm').submit(); //contactForm is your form id
    } else {
        //show errors here & don't submit form
    }
}
```

Give it a try. Will work for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the help.Turned out it was not working because the jquery code was in the header of the index page while the form itself was only loaded onto the page via ajax from a separate html file.

I had to place the jquery code inside the same file as the form.